# "Ultima chance"

Tags: english-comparison, phrase-request, vocabulary, foreign-words

Oggi ho letto in una pubblicità: "Ultima chance per i tuoi regali di Natale: invia un Buono Regalo!" La mia domanda è sull'espressione "ultima chance". Si tratta di un calco dell'inglese "last chance"? Esiste un modo di dire "più italiano" per esprimere la stessa idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Credo che sia più un calco del francese, o almeno mi sembra che la gente tenda a dire "ultima scians", ossia con la pronuncia francese.

Esistono certamente (come in molti altri casi) espressioni italiane equivalenti, per esempio: "ultima occasione", "ultima opportunità".

Però si sa, agli italiani piacciono molto le espressioni straniere.

Comment: La mia esperienza – per quel che vale – e il [vocabolario](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/chance/) confermano che, come dice karoshi, “chance” è per l'italiano un francesismo, che peraltro non si usa solo nella locuzione “ultima chance”.